# HP Autonomy TeamSite 7.3.2 - update details of database used

Tags: database, oracle, customization, teamsite, autonomy

When the Teamsite application is freshly installed, it allows keying in database details. However later when the database login information needs to be updated, TeamSite provides no interface nor documents for updating it.

From my best effort, the most suspected place to be changed is:
/usr/Interwoven/CommonServices/config/private/database.properties

```
#
# database.properties.example
#
# Database connection information for Interwoven Registry Service.
#

# the development database schema connection info
connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:myport:myservicename
connection.username=iwcommon
connection.password=NBk8oBfFLHpwQ4AcM0+el8nr7qfObiBW

database.type=oracle
database.name=myservicename
database.port=myport
database.server=myhost

# orm configuration.
#
# For Microsoft SQL Server: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
# For Oracle:  org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
#
orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect

#
# updateSchemaOnStartup=<true|false>
#
# if true, then ORM synches the mapping files with the tables in the schema.
# if false, existing schema is not changed.
#
#orm.updateSchemaOnStartup=false
```

I have to update it to another Oracle database server with different hostname and service name, but same password. However, authentication error is encountered upon completion of change and reboot. Here is the extracted common service log at /usr/Interwoven/ApplicationContainer/server/default/log/commonservice.log

```
2014-09-01 17:24:48,430 [http-0.0.0.0-8080-4] INFO  org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain () - Interceptor has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Invalid ServiceId/ClientId - Authentication failed
    at com.interwoven.wcm.service.framework.AuthenticationInterceptor.handleMessage(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:220)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:78)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:92)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:283)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:128)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:174)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.doPost(AbstractCXFServlet.java:152)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.interwoven.wcm.service.iwovregistry.common.ConfigException: Invalid ServiceId/ClientId - Authentication failed
    ... 28 more
2014-09-01 17:24:48,444 [http-0.0.0.0-8080-4] WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter () - SQL Error: 12505, SQLState: 66000
2014-09-01 17:24:48,444 [http-0.0.0.0-8080-4] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter () - Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

2014-09-01 17:24:48,444 [http-0.0.0.0-8080-4] ERROR com.interwoven.wcm.service.iwovregistry.adaptors.AbstractBackupAdaptor () - Failed to get TeamSite serviceInfo or IRService home directory when obtaining CSFactory. 
com.interwoven.wcm.service.iwovregistry.common.ConfigException: Exception while reading/writing from Database [ getServiceInfoByComponentName ]
    at com.interwoven.wcm.service.iwovregistry.adaptors.ServiceInfoAdaptor.getServiceInfoByComponentName(ServiceInfoAdaptor.java:674)
    at com.interwoven.wcm.service.iwovregistry.adaptors.AbstractBackupAdaptor.getFactory(AbstractBackupAdaptor.java:422)
    at com.interwoven.wcm.service.iwovregistry.adaptors.AbstractComponentManager.getCSClient(AbstractComponentManager.java:93)
    at com.interwoven.wcm.service.iwovregistry.adaptors.AuthenticateSessionStringAdaptor.authenticateSessionString(AuthenticateSessionStringAdaptor.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.interwoven.wcm.service.iwovregistry.adaptorlayer.AdaptorFactory.invokeAdaptor(AdaptorFactory.java:212)
    at com.interwoven.wcm.service.iwovregistry.servicelayer.ConfigServiceImpl.execute(ConfigServiceImpl.java:92)
    at com.interwoven.wcm.service.framework.AuthenticationInterceptor.authenticateUserByClientId(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:417)
    at com.interwoven.wcm.service.framework.AuthenticationInterceptor.authenticateUser(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:309)
    at com.interwoven.wcm.service.framework.AuthenticationInterceptor.handleMessage(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:220)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:78)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:92)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:283)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:128)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:174)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.doPost(AbstractCXFServlet.java:152)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1353)
    at com.interwoven.wcm.service.iwovregistry.adaptors.ServiceInfoAdaptor.getServiceInfoByComponentName(ServiceInfoAdaptor.java:658)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:412)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:385)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1042)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:301)
    ... 52 more
2014-09-01 17:24:48,446 [http-0.0.0.0-8080-4] ERROR com.interwoven.wcm.service.framework.AuthenticationInterceptor () - Error while parsing incoming message for authentication
com.interwoven.wcm.service.iwovregistry.common.ConfigException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.interwoven.wcm.service.iwovregistry.adaptorlayer.AdaptorFactory.invokeAdaptor(AdaptorFactory.java:264)
    at com.interwoven.wcm.service.iwovregistry.servicelayer.ConfigServiceImpl.execute(ConfigServiceImpl.java:92)
        at com.interwoven.wcm.service.framework.AuthenticationInterceptor.authenticateUserByClientId(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:417)
    at com.interwoven.wcm.service.framework.AuthenticationInterceptor.authenticateUser(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:309)
    at com.interwoven.wcm.service.framework.AuthenticationInterceptor.handleMessage(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:220)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:78)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:92)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:283)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:128)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:174)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.doPost(AbstractCXFServlet.java:152)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.interwoven.wcm.service.iwovregistry.adaptors.AbstractComponentManager.getCSClient(AbstractComponentManager.java:94)
    at com.interwoven.wcm.service.iwovregistry.adaptors.AuthenticateSessionStringAdaptor.authenticateSessionString(AuthenticateSessionStringAdaptor.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.interwoven.wcm.service.iwovregistry.adaptorlayer.AdaptorFactory.invokeAdaptor(AdaptorFactory.java:212)
    ... 31 more
```

Appreciate if anyone knows the correct way of changing the database details. Moreover, I have no idea how is the password formed, so that would also be a problem later, as the policy of my company requires regular database password update. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are your SID and service name the same? Are either valid for the new database? The ORA-12505 suggest you've got the wrong value, and `myservicename` implies you think you're supplying the service rather than the SID. I'd start by seeing what `lsnrctl status` says is recognised on that server.

Answer (score 1):

All versions of TS after 7.1. use an internal database for the event subsystem, so the external DB is no longer used.  The internal DB is ActiveMQ, a file-based database that is integrated into TS directly.

For your remaining databases, if you rename them, here are the associated configuration files that need to be updated in TeamSite:

CommonServices

---

```
CommonServices/config/private/database.properties
```

Reportcenter

---

```
TeamSite/tsreport/conf/spring-config.xml
```

ReportcenterAdv

---

```
ApplicationContainer/server/default/deploy/js-jboss-ds.xml 
ApplicationContainer/server/default/deploy/report-ds.xml
```

You'll also have to open the IR_DBINFO table in the Common Services database and update the database information  there after you change the names.

Restart TS and Reporting after you make the changes.